# How do I generate the content from the `wasm` folder?

Tags: rust, smartcontracts, multiversx, erdpy

I'm trying to build from scratch a smart contract. I'm starting from `cargo new my-contract`.
I wired the MultiversX dependencies and now cargo run does not complain.

Now when I run `mxpy contract build` I get

> FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory:
> '/home/bogdan/workspace/sc-from-scratch/wasm'

When I look at the other templates, I see that the content of this wasm folder is generated.

This is the relevant commit for my question: https://github.com/bogdan-marian/sc-from-scratch/commit/aa6f912e6bca413a91f18c9de52257390645b139

How do I generate the content from the `wasm` folder?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out that there is more to this question than I initially believed. I ended up creating an entire tutorial about how to create from scratch a smart contract. Short version is

- you need to add the wasm folder by hand
- once you add the meta crate later the content of this folder will be generated for you.
  This is where you can see me going through this entire flow:
  https://youtu.be/UYU9Gqw8ldg

Answer (score 0):

Did you try to do a `cargo build` before building the smart contract itself?

It will install dependencies, and generate appropriate folders. If it still does not create the `wasm` folder, did you check your dependencies in your `cargo.toml` file ?

You should have something near this:

```
[package]
name = "router"
version = "0.0.0"
authors = [ "you",]
edition = "2018"
publish = false

[lib]
path = "src/lib.rs"

[features]
wasm-output-mode = [
  "elrond-wasm-node",
  "token_send/wasm-output-mode",
]

[dependencies.token_send]
path = "../../common/modules/token_send"

[dependencies.elrond-wasm]
version = "0.21"
features = ["derive"]

[dependencies.elrond-wasm-derive]
version = "0.21"

[dependencies.elrond-wasm-node]
version = "0.21"
optional = true

[dev-dependencies.elrond-wasm-debug]
version = "0.21"

[dependencies.pair]
path = "../pair"
```

[source](https://github.com/ElrondNetwork/sc-dex-rs/blob/main/dex/router/Cargo.toml)

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest starting out with a wasm folder from one of the example projects, appropriate to the elrond-wasm version you are using.

In newer versions the content of the wasm/src/lib.rs will be generated by the meta subproject you should also have.

In general your life will be a lot easier if you use one of the defined templates using erdpy contract new as described [here](https://github.com/ElrondNetwork/elrond-sdk/blob/master/erdpy/CLI.md#contractnew)

For example

```sh
erdpy contract new --template adder
```